# How can I check that the language of one context-free grammar is a subset of a second context-free grammar?

Tags: parsing, grammar, context-free-grammar, formal-languages, context-free-language

Could you explain me, how can I check, that the language of first context-free grammar (G1) is a subset of the language of second context-free grammar (G2).

G1 and G2 are two LL(1) grammars with identical alphabets:

```
{a, b, c, d, f}
```

Production rules are look like:

```
A -> αB
```

or

```
A -> α
```

and α is a non-epsilon string (of terminal symbols).

Context-free grammar G1:

```
S1 -> aK
K -> bC|cE
C -> cB|d
E -> bA|f
A -> abC
B -> acE
```

Context free grammar G2 :

```
S2 -> aX
X -> bZ|cY
Z -> cV|d
Y -> bU|f
V -> aQ
U -> aP
Q -> cY
P -> bZ
```

**Automatic way is preferred.**

> In additional, how can I check that the languages of two **arbitrary**
>   **context-free grammars** are equal.

Comment: Question also asked here: http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/52495/how-can-i-check-that-the-language-of-one-context-free-grammar-is-a-subset-of-a-s

Comment: In future, please do not cross-post questions. For more information, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Since you have received answers to your question posted on the other site, I'm going to close this one (http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/52495/how-can-i-check-that-the-language-of-one-context-free-grammar-is-a-subset-of-a-s).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it has already been asked, and answered, on cs.stackexchange.com, where it is "more" on topic. http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/52495/how-can-i-check-that-the-language-of-one-context-free-grammar-is-a-subset-of-a-s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Some questions that are undecidable for wider classes of grammars become decidable for context-free grammars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar#Normal_forms)

Language equality is one of the questions that open in cs and not decidable..

but in this case, you can actually build G1' as [Greinbach normal form by Sheila Greibach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greibach_normal_form),

then you can prove L(G2)=L(G1')
by the use of SUBSTITUTION (in order to change the Variants names) on G1' and get exactly G2 grammer.

Answer (score 0):

You actually can't. It's undecidable.

You can show that the problem of determining whether a grammar generates Σ* is undecidable. This means that it's undecidable to test whether two grammars produce the same language, because you could build a grammar for Σ* and testing whether another grammar generates the same language would then let you test whether a grammar has language Σ*, which we know we can't do. You also therefore can't test whether one grammar's language is a subset of another grammar's language, since if you could, you could test whether Σ* is a subset of the language of that grammar, which would then tell you whether the grammar could generate all strings.

Sorry about that!